# Making a dynamic valuation with foreach php

Tags: php, foreach, logic

I want to make a dynamic valuation. So the idea is like this :

- In my database I've user table contains 'score'.
- And I've category table contains fields 'minScore' and 'categoryName(bad, good, awesome)'
- And In the end I want to get result like this categoryName=>howMuchUserBasedOnScore.

I'm thinking like this :

```
function valuation(){
$allScore = $this->db->select('score')->get('user')->result();
$category = $this->db->get('categori')->result();

$arrCategori = array();

foreach ($allScore as $value) {
  foreach($categori as $row){
    if($value->score <= $row->minScore){
      array_push($arrCategori, )
      //I don't know what should I do
    }
  }
}
```

}

can anyone help me?

edit :

- Now I add maxScore into my category table field.
- and I changed the if statement. it become like this

  ```
  if($value->score <= $row->minScore && $value->score >= $row->maxScore){
      array_push($arrCategori, $arrCategori[$row->Categori] = $value->bsc );
    }
  ```
- I var_dump it. and the result is what I expected. the problem now is that, how can I count how much people that are awesome, bad or good

edit :

- here's the var_dump from $allscore (I change bsc into score for the sake simplicity):

  ```
  array(11) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#42 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(6) "100.00" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#43 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(5) "40.00" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#44 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(6) "100.00" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#45 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(6) "100.00" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#46 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(5) "40.00" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#47 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(5) "40.00" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#48 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(5) "40.00" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#49 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(5) "40.00" } [8]=> object(stdClass)#50 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(5) "40.00" } [9]=> object(stdClass)#51 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(5) "60.00" } [10]=> object(stdClass)#52 (1) { ["bsc"]=> string(4) "0.00" } }
  ```
- var_dump from $category (bxnak = maxScore, bxnaw = minScore)

  ```
  array(9) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#53 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["bxnaw"]=> string(1) "0" ["bxnak"]=> string(2) "25" ["kategori"]=> string(5) "GAGAL" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#54 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["bxnaw"]=> string(2) "26" ["bxnak"]=> string(2) "40" ["kategori"]=> string(16) "DALAM PENGAWASAN" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#55 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["bxnaw"]=> string(2) "41" ["bxnak"]=> string(2) "50" ["kategori"]=> string(18) "PERLU PENGEMBANGAN" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#56 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["bxnaw"]=> string(2) "51" ["bxnak"]=> string(2) "60" ["kategori"]=> string(5) "BURUK" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#57 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["bxnaw"]=> string(2) "61" ["bxnak"]=> string(2) "75" ["kategori"]=> string(11) "KURANG BAIK" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#58 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["bxnaw"]=> string(2) "76" ["bxnak"]=> string(2) "80" ["kategori"]=> string(10) "CUKUP BAIK" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#59 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["bxnaw"]=> string(2) "81" ["bxnak"]=> string(2) "90" ["kategori"]=> string(4) "BAIK" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#60 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["bxnaw"]=> string(2) "91" ["bxnak"]=> string(2) "99" ["kategori"]=> string(11) "SANGAT BAIK" } [8]=> object(stdClass)#61 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9" ["bxnaw"]=> string(3) "100" ["bxnak"]=> string(4) "1000" ["kategori"]=> string(8) "ISTIMEWA" } }
  ```

Comment: `$arrCategori[$row] = $value->score`  ???

Comment: I got error array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: Have you delete `array_push($arrCategori, );` ?

Comment: nope, I followed your code. I change it

Comment: sorry my mistake, i deleted it, but I fixed it. and now the error become Illegal offset type

Comment: Update your code question and add please `var_dump` or `print_r` of `$allScore` and `$categori`  please.

Comment: You wrong don't use `array_push` but just my code `if($value->score <= $row->minScore && $value->score >= $row->maxScore){
    $arrCategori[$row->Categori] = $value->bsc
  }`

Comment: I see now _how can I count how much people that are awesome, bad or good_

Comment: yea, I want count the people. can you give me an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it!!

so here's the final code of my function

```
function valuation(){
$allBsc = $this->db->select('bsc')->get('kpi')->result();
$kategori = $this->db->get('kategori')->result();


$arrKategori = [];

foreach ($allBsc as $value) {
  foreach($kategori as $row){
    if($value->bsc <= $row->bxnak && $value->bsc >= $row->bxnaw){
      if(array_key_exists($row->kategori, $arrKategori)){
        array_push($arrKategori[$row->kategori], $value->bsc);
      }else{
        array_push($arrKategori, $arrKategori[$row->kategori] = array($value->bsc));
      }
    }
  }
}
var_dump(count($arrKategori));
die();
```

}

thank you, for helping me!

- $allBsc = $score
- $kategori = $category
- $arrKategori = $allCategory